# Issue with using xxd command on Windows: CommandNotFoundException

Tags: c++, model, esp32, tflite

I'm facing an issue with using the `xxd` command on Windows. Whenever I try to execute the command, I receive the following error: "CommandNotFoundException: xxd is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

I have tried the following solutions, but none of them resolved the issue:

1. Installing Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL): I installed WSL and tried running the `xxd` command within the Linux environment, but the same error persists.

2. Downloading a precompiled `xxd` binary: I searched for precompiled `xxd` binaries for Windows and tried using them, but I still encounter the same error.

I understand that `xxd` is commonly found in Unix-like environments such as Linux or macOS, but I need to perform this conversion on a Windows system. Are there any alternative solutions or workarounds that I can try to achieve the same result?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to resolve this issue and successfully convert the `model.tflite` file to a C/C++ array format on Windows.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I am attempting to convert a binary file (`model.tflite`) to a C/C++ array format using `xxd` as part of a project. However, it seems that the `xxd` command-line tool is not recognized on my Windows system.

Comment: `xxd` works in WSL for me. It was installed by default, but if you do not have it then `sudo apt install xxd` should install it. If you downloaded a binary that is supposed to run in Windows you won't be able to run it from the Windows command line unless you supply the full pathname to it or add the directory where it is installed to your path.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what you've tried

Comment: I'm using windows